# Save JSON results in [CLLocation] SWIFT

Tags: json, swift, swift3, swifty-json

My code fetches the places nearby a specific location. I managed to get the coordinates of the all the locations nearby and the json looks like this:

**UPDATED JSON**

this is what json structure looks like

```
{
  "results" : [
    {
      "id" : "6a70e8bec1fd7429c3107bb53ff0663b68750b7d",
      "rating" : 4.2999999999999998,
      "vicinity" : "6169 طريق الأمير تركي بن عبدالعزيز الأول، الرياض",
      "scope" : "GOOGLE",
      "geometry" : {
        "viewport" : {
          "northeast" : {
            "lat" : 24.725911030291499,
            "lng" : 46.646357630291497
          },
          "southwest" : {
            "lat" : 24.723213069708489,
            "lng" : 46.643659669708498
          }
        },
        "location" : {
          "lat" : 24.7244879,
          "lng" : 46.645116399999999
        }
      },
      "icon" : "https:\/\/maps.gstatic.com\/mapfiles\/place_api\/icons\/restaurant-71.png",
      "place_id" : "ChIJebIILG8dLz4Rwh96XLe4lDk",
      "opening_hours" : {
        "weekday_text" : [

        ],
        "open_now" : true
      },
      "photos" : [
        {
          "width" : 960,
          "height" : 1280,
          "html_attributions" : [
            "<a href=\"https:\/\/maps.google.com\/maps\/contrib\/111982605117618652897\/photos\">*خارج الخدمه* *مؤقتا*<\/a>"
          ],
          "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAkcQXErGTRgMEXeTRjXyqdJxiOD9Bq3ApLu9MfiWXjd1gGaJ7LRmSm19mJdXuT8q-KD3Pg0XuK4rAAA_-JwQl8iAo-y3jx8oQ4Zn3hBRJkHBgzXxvIyQrs3Nd-JKinQdgEhCYkgEXcPpPtT0Z7tc1_FOxGhSQFuKsRZFDeRW5AUy9VLAR3MdRUA"
        }
      ],
      "reference" : "CmRRAAAAYXlBsUXQooQOBk0EWmHmoRFbX4cCqm7bYUm0U2ODQYwqv8fXNCgxbFFuZp2m8NHT-La7Zdk6WDY0eGdJqBIyT08sqyY-b4vZFjHZY32CQXYdaKtjT54YDeXglWRRKcAdEhD0imBkJB_luly2EbQNFA47GhSUrev3SNxuTvSRCARzjOZ6zwt3bw",
      "name" : "Hamburgini هامبرغيني",
      "types" : [
        "restaurant",
        "food",
        "point_of_interest",
        "establishment"
      ]
    },
```

How can I save the result in 
`var coordinate: [CLLocation] = [CLLocation]()` So eventually I can pick the closest place to another coordinate ?

my code:

```
Alamofire.request(urlStr).responseJSON
            { response in
               if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
                        //Handle the results as JSON

                        let data = JSON(value)

                for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in  data["results"] {

                    let array = subJson["geometry"]["location"]


                }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you can try this, but depending on what you need I suggest to create your Model and init it with your JSON data.

```
for (_, jsonDict): (String, JSON) in data["results"] {
    guard let location = jsonDict[“geometry”][“location”] as? [String: Any] else { return }

    if let latitude = location[“lat”] as? Double, let longitude = location[“lng”] as? Double {
       let locationCoord = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
       coordinate.append(locationCoord) 
    }
}
```

Comment: `Value of tuple type '(key: String, value: JSON)' has no member 'subscript'` next to `coord[“lat”] ` I think the json response is a dictionary not an array

Comment: @leo0019 I thought your variable array contains all the dictionaries with the coordinates. I will edit my answer.

Comment: look at my answer!! somehow this works for me but I still think there's something odd going on

Comment: @leo0019 It depends on your Json structure, without seeing more I cannot help you :/

Comment: check my question again please

Comment: @leo0019 I have edited my answer, I would do it this way.

Comment: it still gives me an error `Value of tuple type '(String, JSON)' has no member 'subscript'`

Comment: @leo0019 Try now.

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = subJson["geometry"]["location"].dictionaryValue
                for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in array {
                    // Do something you want


                    let latitude = array["lat"]?.doubleValue
                    let longitude = array["lng"]?.doubleValue
                    let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)
                        self.coordinate.append(location)
```